# Проблема с созданием проекта под Android в eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Привет всем.

Как не возникнет необходимость написать что-то под android в eclipse, так постоянно напарываешься на какую-то странную ошибку. Я не имею достаточного опыта работы в этой среде и не могу понять что ей нужно, как ни странно это не звучит, но eclipse просто не создает проект. Сделал бы в Android Studio, но нужно именно в эклипсе(

Сперва скачал эклипс неон, он не мог создать проект под андроид. Затем скачал oxygen, та же беда. Затем залез в SDK manager и повыделял почти все:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

результат - работать ничего не стало. Выдает вот такую ошибку при попытке создания проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее среда выкинет вот такое сообщение, если быть очень навязчивым и пытаться все же повторно нажать на кнопку создания проекта:

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Android
>   Resource Manager' on project 'Teest'. java.lang.NullPointerException

На эклипсе вообще что-то серьезное делают?

Пока писал этот вопрос среда выкинула какое-то сообщение и закрылась ;D
Что ей надо для работы, чего он хочет?

Comment: *На эклипсе вообще что-то серьезное делают?* - делают, и немало чего :)

Comment: Подскажите как быть, почему он нехочет работать?

Comment: Создайте в Андроид Студии проект, а потом имортните его в Эклипс :)

Comment: А разве плагин для работы под Android в Eclipse ещё развивается?

Comment: Дело в том, что Google уже как год поставил крест на Eclipse в качестве среды разработки под Android (в пользу Android Studio) и плагин ADT с тех пор не поддерживается ими (отдан сообществу), поэтому лучше изыскать возможность разрабатывать в Android Studio, чем портить нервы, реанимируя Eclipse ADT (при этом гарантировано будут проблемы с актуальными либами и возможностями платформы Android) . Кстати, вы [плагин ADT (android development tool)](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)  установили, насколько я помню, в стандартную поставку он не входит.

Comment: @Suvitruf пока да https://github.com/khaledev/ADT

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, что-то из нижеследующего поможет:

- Поменяйте `WorkSpace`: `File` – `Switch Workspace`;
- При создании проекта не создавайте `activity`. Создайте ее вручную после создания проекта;
- У кого-то проблема решалось сменой версии `JDK`;
- [Создайте файл](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20300476) `project.properties`.

(с) просторов SO.